# jQuery: how to select dynamically created html elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have these dynamically created text fields using jQuery:

```
<div class="row"><input type="text" id="product_price_1"><input type="text" id="product_quantity_1"><input type="text" id="product_total_price_1"></div>
<div class="row"><input type="text" id="product_price_2"><input type="text" id="product_quantity_2"><input type="text" id="product_total_price_2"></div>
<div class="row"><input type="text" id="product_price_3"><input type="text" id="product_quantity_3"><input type="text" id="product_total_price_3"></div>
```

the values come from the database and the number of rows vary.
this is what i did in my .js file:

```
    $('#product_quantity_1').change(function() {
       $('#product_total_price_1').val(
            $('#product_price_1').val()*$('#product_quantity_1').val()
        );
    });
```

what i did works, the the total price changes when i input a different product quantity
i also want to access the other input fields, and put a .change() event but the number would always vary
how to deal with this? thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/ms4kQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a common class to related elements, like a common class to all price elements ex

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="product_price_1" class="product_price">
    <input type="text" id="product_quantity_1" class="product_quantity">
    <input type="text" id="product_total_price_1" class="product_total_price">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="product_price_2" class="product_price">
    <input type="text" id="product_quantity_2" class="product_quantity">
    <input type="text" id="product_total_price_2" class="product_total_price">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="product_price_3" class="product_price">
    <input type="text" id="product_quantity_3" class="product_quantity">
    <input type="text" id="product_total_price_3" class="product_total_price">
</div>
```

then

```
$('.product_quantity').change(function () {
    $(this).next('.product_total_price').val(($(this).prev('.product_price').val() * this.value) || 0);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LnXTN/)

Comment: this a very nice example but what if i have to use id attribute?